# Build a scheduler, to simulate parallel game flow

Tags: discussion

I been asking a [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28409/build-a-scheduler-to-simulate-parallel-game-flow) in Computer Science and it been placed on hold, as they did not understood me.

I want to clarify this question and ask it here. Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That question appears to have little to do with mathematics.  It also cannot be accurately answered until you have completely clarified all of the rules and constraints of your desired scheduler. Most of this has been mentioned to you in comments to your question.  Additionally, cross-posting questions between Stack Exchange sites is [highly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/214632).

IMHO, you are *much* better off simply thinking through all of the requirements you have of this scheduler, and improve your already asked question.  (After editing, your question will become a candidate for re-opening, though the more improvements you make to the question will increase its chances of being re-opened.)

Comment: I just don't understand what qualifications I need to add. This is what I am trying to understand

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman: Are there any actions that must occur before other actions? Are there actions which can occur in parallel? How "long" do actions take? Do any actions affect the outcomes of other (subsequent) actions? (Presumably a `Remove Self` action would have to remove all subsequent actions by that unit.) Before designing the scheduler, you really should have a pretty good idea of how your actions are supposed to work, both individually and an concert.

Comment: "How long do action take?" Isn't it clear from action definition that it has 4 parts and one of them is action time? In rules I say: "after unit removed him self he cannot perform any actions" isn't that part clear? You are helping me a lot, thank you. Just trying to understand the confusion. "Are there any actions that must occur before other actions", in rules says: "Same unit cannot perform two actions in parallel", but same unit may need to perform more than one action. So I want to make all the actions in parallel but there are rules limitations, and I ask how to over come them.

Comment: "Are there any actions that must occur before other actions" I believe that this question is answered in "Same unit cannot perform two actions in parallel", I just don't know how to make this clear. Eventually I am am searching after algorithm that will be generic for all the actions with my given structure and general rulls.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman to a computerprogram  nothing is clear, as you set it up an unit will never take damage (because the action is never started) you needto be very precise, and the best way is - first study it better, also i am not sure if CS is the best stack exchange site to ask it maybe http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ is the best place

Comment: @Willemien I would defiantly try gamedev. But first I need to be able explain my self. Why do you think action will never start?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman it is never triggered

Comment: @Willemien It mentioned in the bottom, the goal is to create a scheduler that will tell when to trigger the actions. What did I missed here?

Comment: @see I am no programmer better ask it at the game dev site :)

Comment: Arthur, I did as you suggested and edit it. I hope it will be reopened.